# How to check if point on line, point in circle (asymptote)?

Tags: asymptote

In Asymptote, how can I check if a point is on a line within a tolerance?

Also, how can I check if a point is in a circle?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site.  Can you clarify the following in your question?  Are you looking for a function to check whether a given point is inside a circular path?  Are you also looking for a function to check whether a given point is on a linear path of finite length?  Must the point be exactly on the line, or on the line within a tolerance?  Thank you.

Comment: There is a function called "inside" in the asymptote manual (in the section about paths).  You give the function a pair and a cyclic path.  It returns a boolean.

Comment: Tks James,

I write function to check POL:

bool g2POL(point A, line m) 
{ 
 real min=1/10^15;
 point H=midpoint(A--reflect(m)*A);
 if (abs(A-H)<min) return true;
 else return false; 
}

Comment: Looks good!  You should answer your own question with that function.  You should include in your answer that you are using the `geometry` package.  You might consider making the tolerance "min" value an argument of your function.  For example, `bool g2POL(point A, line m, real tolerance=1e-15)`

Comment: I now see that there is a function already in the `geometry` package for distance from a point to a line.  You could use it to make your function simpler.  `real distance(point M, line l)`

Answer (score 1):

The following code demonstrates the solution to your two questions using the `geometry` package in `asymptote`.

```
import geometry;
unitsize(1inch);

point p1 = (0.0,0.0);
point p2 = (1.0,1.0);

path c = circle((0,0), 1);
write(inside(c, (pair) p1));
write(inside(c, (pair) p2));

line l = line(p1, (1,-1));
write(distance(p1, l));
write(distance(p2, l));

bool pointOnLine(line l, point p, real tolerance=1e-8) {
    return distance(p, l) < tolerance;
}

write(pointOnLine(l, p2));
write(pointOnLine(l, p2, 2.0));

draw(c);
dot(Label("p1 (0,0)"), p1, red);
dot(Label("p2 (1,1)"), p2, red);
draw(l, blue);
```

The output of the 6 `write();` commands are as follows.

```
true
false
0
1.41421356237309
false
true
```

Notes:

1. The `inside` function is a built-in command for a cyclic `path` and a `pair`.  A `point` must be cast to a `pair` as shown to use this function.
2. I have created a function to test if a point is on a line.  It incorporates the `distance` function.  A tolerance may be given.  If not given, the tolerance defaults to `1e-8`.  In the second demonstration of this function, I give a large tolerance of `2.0`.

[image]

Comment: There is a operator @: (A @ m) return true if and only if the point A belongs to the line (or circle, ...) m.